# Using Stokes theorem to compute a surface integral

Tags: stokes-theorem

Edit: bound the unit sphere surface by $ z \ge 0 , y \ge 0, x \ge 0 $

Given the surface  $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ of unit sphere,  I need to compute the surface integral of

$\int \int_{D} F \cdot ds  $ on  part of the sphere where $ z \ge 0 , y \ge 0, x \ge 0 $ and where $F = [0,x,0]$ is a vector field.

Instead of computing the surface integral I wanted to use Stoke's theorem and compute a line integral over the quarter unit cycle in the $xy$ plane ($y \ge 0, x \ge 0$) that bounds the surface. I was able to guess a vector field $G = [xz,0,0]$ for which $\nabla   \times G = [0,x,0] = F $

I thought that the line integral $ \oint G \cdot dr $ over the quarter unit circle in the $xy$ plane ($y \ge 0, x \ge 0$) equals to the surface integral.  But since the line integral evaluated for $z=0$  and then $G = [xz,0,0] = [0,0,0]$ and the line integral trivially evaluates to zero.

What do I do wrong here ( I know that zero is not the correct result for the surface integral)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to apply divergence theorem? It screams divergence theorem: $\operatorname{div}F=\partial_xF_1+\partial_yF_2+\partial_zF_3=0$ and $\langle F,e_3\rangle =0.$

Comment: There is nothing wrong, some integrals are just $0$. Whoever told you the answer is not zero is wrong. And I can prove it is zero with a simple odd/even function symmetry on the original surface integral, no theorems, as the vector surface integral simplifies to the following scalar surface integral $$\iint xy \:dS$$

Comment: I'll modify the question so that the surface  in only when $x>0, y>0, z>0$ - will it still hold ?

Comment: You haven't edited your work accordingly. Because now the boundary is not solely in the $z=0$ plane.

Comment: Why the boundary is not only in z=0 ? can you explain ? I guess I'm struggling with the definition of a curve that is bounding a surface.